# How to set header for JTable?

Tags: java, swing

With below example code:

```
String column_names[]= {"Serial Number","Medicine Name","Dose","Frequency"};
table_model=new DefaultTableModel(column_names,3);
table=new JTable(table_model);
```

We want to set header with names of columns as in column_names with the above code but it is not working. Header is not visible though table is getting created.

Comment: According to the guidelines, you should use camelCase in stead of '_': tableModel and columnNames. See http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To be able to see the header, you should put the table in a JScrollPane.

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Or you could specifically add the tableHeader to your panel if you really don't want a scrollpane (but: normally you don't want this behaviour):

```
panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that adding the header and table in `NORTH` and `CENTER` of a panel has a different behavior. When the table is added to a scrollpane via `new JScrollPane(table)`, then the header is **fixed** - meaning that it will stay on top when scrolling. With the panel-based apporach, scrolling will move the header out of the viewport, which is likely not desired.

Answer (score 2):

[See here for more information about JTables and TableModels](http://www.chka.de/swing/table/faq.html)

JTable Headers only get shown when the Table is in a scroll pane, which is usually what you want to do anyway. If for some reason, you need to show a table without a scroll pane, you can do:

```
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MessageFormat header = null;

if (this.headerBox.isSelected())
{
  header = new MessageFormat(gradesLabel.toString());
}

MessageFormat footer = null;

if (this.footerBox.isSelected())
{
  footer = new MessageFormat(this.footerField.getText());
}

boolean fitWidth = this.fitWidthBox.isSelected();
boolean showPrintDialog = this.showPrintDialogBox.isSelected();
boolean interactive = this.interactiveBox.isSelected();

JTable.PrintMode mode = fitWidth ? JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH : 
  JTable.PrintMode.NORMAL;
try
{
  boolean complete = this.gradesTable.print(mode, header, footer, 
    showPrintDialog, null, 
    interactive, null);

  if (complete)
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
      "Printing Complete", 
      "Printing Result", 
      1);
  }
  else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
      "Printing Cancelled", 
      "Printing Result", 
      1);
}
catch (PrinterException pe)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, 
    "Printing Failed: " + pe.getMessage(), 
    "Printing Result", 
    0);
}
```

Actually the Jtable object has one method, which is print() menthod, which is used to pass the header and footer as parameter to print 
Here headerBox is Jcheckbox which one i created in my program
and also here some Jlabels are also there. If you dont need that means remove those from this code and run the program