# How do i add table heading while loading a table in my JAVA GUI from sqlite database in eclipse?

Tags: java, database, swing, sqlite

Ok, so i am learning how to use sqlite database with JAVA and i am learning the various operations. One operation that i came across was loading the records from the sqlite database to my table in my GUI program. Now, my program really works fine and it shows no problem but wouldn't it be better if i can a header to my table when it loads the data from the sqlite database. Can someone please help me out as how i can add this feature to my program. Here is the load records from table method.

```
btnLoadallrecords = new JButton("LoadAllRecords");

        btnLoadallrecords.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

PreparedStatement pat;

                try {
                    String query = "select Lender,Borrower,Money,Date from Records";
                    pat = connection.prepareStatement(query);

                    ResultSet rs = pat.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));





                }

                catch (Exception j)
                {

                }


                }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [How to set header for JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297991/how-to-set-header-for-jtable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like...

[image: JTable]

With column headers?  Then you should be wrapping your `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`

Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details

Comment: :- You are not only a mad programmer but an awesome programmer. We need people like you! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Oh, I assure you, I'm completely insane ;)